# NDB SortBy no results for ComputedProperty

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, gcloud

im not 100% sure with this, but in my Opinion NDB queries have problems when `sortBy` a `ComputedProperty` is used.
In my example below sorting by `name` works without as expected, while sorting by the `numberOfProducts` does not return any entries. However if I sort by `name` the correct values for `numberOfProducts` are returned, which implies the model itself and the database are fine.

My Model:

```
class Brand(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    products = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: Product.query(Product.brand==self.key).fetch(keys_only=True))
    numberOfProducts = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: len(self.products))
```

My Query:

```
sortBy = Brand._properties[args['sortBy']]
query = query.order(-sortBy if args['asc'] == '0' else +sortBy)
entities, cursor, more = query.fetch_page(20, start_cursor=Cursor(urlsafe=args['cursor']))
```

Thanks a lot for any cause for thought.

Comment: I suggest you perform a simple example of the query sorting by the computed property.  (ie remove other possible variable behaviour) and see if you can sort correctly. Also where is query coming from. e.g `Brand.query().order(-Brand.numberOfProducts)`

Comment: My bad I didn't mention, I tried exactly the query you mentioned, I do not get any entities with it either. I also do not get any error/warning, I just get an empty result.

Comment: So how is query defined ?

Comment: when did you add the computed property and have you checked with the datastore viewer that the value exists in the datastore ?  If it was added later, and no put() has been performed then the value will not be in the index.  What you will be seeing is the value computed as a result of the get(). Hence the sort won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the problem, even if I have no clue why this leads to this unexpected behavior.
Basically my computedProperty `products` causes the problem:

```
products = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: Product.query(Product.brand==self.key).fetch(keys_only=True))
```

This query returns a `list` of keys and therefore the property needs the `repeated` argument to be set. Has anyone an idea whats the cause why this error leads to my error?

Comment: That code will return a list of keys. And a ComputedProperty doesn't by default store lists.  Also this computed property is really inefficient.  It will always evaluate when you retrieve the record.  Which I don't think is what you intend.    So the only value `products` property will have is if you use it in an index (ie faking a join).

Comment: I totally understand the mistake, but I do not understand why this resulted in my described error.
In my case I want to compute this every time I query the brand, because I want to be sure I always get and up2date list of productKeys. As far as I can see this is the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: I suppose if you "every" time you retrieve the entity that you do in fact want to perform the query then yes it is reasonably efficient. However there is no point in storing the list of keys then.  You would only want to store the len.  In addition you may find it better then to use the `post_get` hook and perform the query with that approach rather than having to store redundant information.

Comment: However if your code where to get() the entity multiple times in a single  front facing request or in subsequent queries performed within a few seconds (possibly up to a minute), then this very inefficient.  The nature of eventual consistency is such you cannot guarantee the data is up to date unless you where to perform the query using entity groups.  So you could perform lots of possibly inaccurate queries in a short space of time.